# jQuery: On click on native audio element

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, html5-audio

How can you detect a click on the native browser's audio element with jQuery?

Doesn't seem to work in Chrome.

```js
$('audio').click(function(){
    alert("You clicked on some audio player");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<audio preload="none" src="http://webaudioapi.com/samples/audio-tag/chrono.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" controls=""></audio>
```

http://codepen.io/Subfader/pen/GqrmNQ

Comment: The `<audio>` element controls are encapsulated within `shadowDOM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in saying that it doesn't seem to be able to call the native audio tag in the usual way, neither using vanilla js nor jquery. I tried using a class (which i thought would be successful) but to no avail.

However, that said I think I have a solution to your overall problem. Try out the below snippet. When one player is selected, the others stop. (only one plays at a time).

You could extend this by perhaps adding a visible class when playing an making the visibility set to hidden or display:none by default (but actually then how would you click play? - hmmm) Anyway, point is, customise as you wish.

hope this helps

```js
$("audio").each(function(index) {
  var num = index+1;
  $(this).attr('id','myaudio' + num);
});

document.addEventListener('play', function(e){
    var aplayers = $('audio');
    var leng = $('audio').length;
    //console.log(leng);
    for(var i = 0; i < leng;i++){
        if (aplayers[i] != e.target){
            aplayers[i].pause();
        }
    }
}, true);
```

```css
audio{margin-bottom:10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio id=' '  controls src="http://www.soundjay.com//mechanical/gun-cocking-01.mp3">
</audio>

<audio id=' ' src="http://www.rachelgallen.com/monkey.mp3" controls>
</audio>

<audio preload="none" src="http://webaudioapi.com/samples/audio-tag/chrono.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" controls=""></audio>
```

Comment: Thanks, my if-play-check was stuck. Yours is global.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look like it works with even using plain JavaScript in Chrome. I would suggest that you wrap your `<audio>` element in a div and place the click event on that element instead.

Or depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you could bind to other [Media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) such as `play`, `pause` or `seek`.

Comment: Well, it seems like you can't even trigger events in the capturing phase when clicking on the audio element. What are you trying to accomplish with this? Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: When an audio player is clicked on (e.g. "play") I want to pause all other possibly playing invisible audios by clicking a dedicated button.

So something like on visibleAudioElement > click > click on span.buttonForInvisibleAudios

Comment: @Martin _"When an audio player is clicked on (e.g. "play") I want to pause all other possibly playing invisible audios by clicking a dedicated button. So something like on visibleAudioElement > click > click on span.buttonForInvisibleAudios"_ Consider including this description at Question?

Comment: So you can't bind to the `play` event of the audio element to get this done?

Comment: How, if I can't even alert on click.